# Need basic encryption understanding from existing Android code

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I am new in Android and I have started to working on existing project which have some encryption algorithm,

Below is existing code

```
    var secureRandom = SecureRandom()
    var masterKey = ByteArray(32)
    secureRandom.nextBytes(masterKey)

    var keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
    keyGen.initialize(2048)

    var keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair()

    var pubKey = keyPair.public

    var subjectPublicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(pubKey.encoded))
    var pubKeyEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(subjectPublicKeyInfo.parsePublicKey().encoded, Base64.DEFAULT)

    var sb = StringBuilder()
    sb.append("-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n")
    sb.append(pubKeyEncoded)
    sb.append("\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n")

    val publicKey = sb.toString()

    val privateKey = keyPair.private as RSAPrivateKey
    val string = StringWriter()
    var writer = PemWriter(string)
    writer.writeObject(privateKey)//<-----Getting an error like Type Mismatch
    writer.close()
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue, I am totally new in this encryption fields, anyone suggest me from where I can get deeper understanding on cryptography,

from above code I have just understand that we are getting two keys like public key and private key for AES

We are encrypting public key by below code

```
  var subjectPublicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.getInstance(pubKey.encoded))
    var pubKeyEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(subjectPublicKeyInfo.parsePublicKey().encoded, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

But I still did not understand what will be use of SubjectPublicKeyInfo, ASN1Sequence, PemWriter if anyone have knowledge then please explain me.

I am also getting compile time error like Required **PemObjectGenerator!** found **RSAPrivateKey**

Comment: I think this article will help you to understand the Encryption. https://proandroiddev.com/security-best-practices-symmetric-encryption-with-aes-in-java-7616beaaade9

Comment: HI @JAYMIN first of all thanks, but still  that can not justify with above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not help you in more detail but one thing i have found that

PEMWriter is already deprecated. You are not getting this message because you are importing PEMWritter from different package like util package

Instead import it from

```
org.spongycastle.openssl.PEMWriter
```

at that time you will get warning like it is deprecated so instead of use below

```
JcaPEMWriter
```

it is by using following package

```
org.spngycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter
```

your error will be gone

Comment: OK Let me try that